# Relaying Serial Data in Lion

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, osx-lion

So I have my computer linked up via bluetooth to two different devices, and I'd like to relay the input from one device to the other device automatically.

I figure I can do this with a script, but I'm pretty green with scripting languages, and I'm not even sure if this is possible.

I know that like Linux, OSX treats serial ports as if they were file directories, so I figure this can't be too hard.  I just have no idea where to start.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a simple python script.  Manipulating serial ports is simple with the [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html) module.  Then create thread for each port that reads from one port and writes to the other.

Comment: One great thing about python is that the user community is huge, and you can find countless online tutorials and help.  The official docs are pretty good: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/  Also, a popular source of info is the Dive Into Python book: http://www.diveintopython.net/toc/index.html  Play around a bit, trying to get your program to work, then you can ask specific questions on Stack Overflow

Comment: Cool.  I'll give this a try and post the code...  But it might be a while -_-;  This was meant as a patch fix for a pair of devices that wouldn't pair with each other, and they just started pairing.  The urgency has left, but I'll try and implement this for the community and my own benefit.